# Find pattern and append in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am having difficulty to find a pattern and append line before the pattern in sed

Suppose i want to find the following pattern with sed

```
"stackov/er;flo.w users are great"
```

**Note:The pattern to be search contain double quotes , /, ; and dot**
And then append this line just before pattern

```
proud sta{ckov,er member
```

My attempts

1.`sed "|"stackov/er;flo.w users are great"|i\proud sta{ckov,er member" file`

2.

```
sed "/stackov/er;flo.w users are great|i\proud sta{ckov,er member" file
```

I tried to replace the / delimiter by | and then escaping / in pattern with \ but it didn't work.

Any help appreciated

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/"stackov\/er;flo\.w users are great"/i\proud sta{ckov,er member' file
```

Comment: Thanks dude ...how will the command change if double quotes are found in search pattern like "stackov/er;flo.w us"ers are great"

Comment: If you single quote the command(s) (as in the solution), double quotes are treated the same as any other non-meta character i.e. they do not need to be quoted. – potong 11 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're on Windows (in which case I don't know), you basically want the entire `sed` script in single quotes, not double.

```
sed '\|"stackov/er;flo.w users are great"|i\proud sta{ckov,er member' file
```

You can make it work with double quotes as well, but unless you specifically require double quotes, you should default to single quotes. Read up on [the shell's quoting behavior](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) if you want to use it in the future as well.