# Using an append pattern sed on AIX

Tags: sed, append, aix

I have been struggling trying to find a pattern with sed and then append a character on AIX.
I have absolutely no problem on Linux, but I really don't get how it is supposed to work on AIX.

Very simple :
I have a /tmp/test.txt :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And I want :

```
1
2
10
3
4
5
```

So that I can understand how it works on AIX.

On Linux, I can do

```
sed -i '/2/ a 10\' /tmp/test.txt
```

It works. On AIX, I know we have to do a work around because there's no -i. But even after looking at other topics like 
[Find pattern and append in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169984/find-pattern-and-append-in-sed)

I tried that, following their example

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | sed '/2/i\10' > /tmp/test.temp
cat /tmp/test.txt | sed '\|"2"|i\10' > /tmp/test.temp
```

And probably dozen of other combinaisons, but I get something like it can't be parsed, or it's not reconized as a function. Or it can be run, but when I look at test.temp, nothing happened.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIX!sed doesn't support GNU-extension, only the strict Posix-format (including the line-break after the `a\` part). For example:

```
sed '/pattern/a\
insert after pattern
/pattern2/i\
insert before pattern2 - first line\
insert before pattern2 - second line'
```

Comment: So it seems I have to write what I want on the next line, after a carriage return. 
And it works. Thanks !