# How to insert a Line into a file in AIX using sed preferably?

Tags: aix

I want to insert a line "new line" into a file "Textfile.txt" at line number 3 in AIX.

Before insertion Textfile.txt looks like

```
one
two
four
```

After Insertion Textfile.txt looks like

```
one
two
new line
four
```

I have already done it on Linux how ever with AIX I am finding it not working with solution of Linux.

Surprisingly I couldn't find a simple solution for this problem anywhere.

I am using this command in Linux and is working

```
echo "target_node = ${arr[0]}"
echo "target_file = ${arr[1]}"
echo "target_line = ${arr[2]}"
echo "target_text = ${arr[3]}"
```

escape "$(ssh -f ${arr[0]} **"sed -i "${arr[2]}i$(escape ${arr[3]})"** ${arr[1]}; exit")"

Comment: How did you do it on Linux, and how is that failing on AIX?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-place editing using sed on AIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111673). *Summary:* Use perl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280212/using-an-append-pattern-sed-on-aix/62290094

Comment: hi @LorinczyZsigmond  i tried this but no luck as i wanted to insert a text at given line number (cant look for a pattern as its variable)

Comment: Don't show code in comments. **Edit** the question and add relevant information there, where it can be well-formatted. Delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

To sum the previous bits of information written as comments:
Option `-i` doesn't exist in AIX!sed, use a temporary file; the syntax of command is more strict than in Linux.

```
sed '2a\
Insert this after the 2nd line' "$target_file" >"$target_file.tmp"
mv -- "$target_file.tmp" "$target_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for the help,

I created script in such a way that it copies the file to linux update changes and movies to AIX.

[image]